# Retrieve data, which has a date range, within the current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table `Event` which has `startDate` and `endDate` columns

I only want to get the events that are happening in the current month.

If I have an event that is from Aug-29, 2019, to Sep-1, 2019, and I want to retrieve all events in September, that event should be in the result. (that event should also appear in August results)

Also, consider when the event crosses another year.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT EventTitle AS 'Event Name'
    ,CompleteAddress AS 'Location'
    ,UserId AS 'Event Creator'
FROM Event
WHERE
Month(StartDate) = Month(getdate()) 
AND Year(StartDate) = Year(getdate())
```

But this only considers the startDate.

Comment: please show some sample data and the required result

Comment: @Sami that won't work for events with schedules from Aug to Nov and you wanted September data only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want events that are active specific month (regardless of when they start or end) you want events where the start date is prior to the start of the next month, and the end date is on or after the start of the desired month:

```
DECLARE @MonthStart date = '20190901';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Event] E
WHERE E.StartDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@MonthStart))
  AND E.EndDate >= @MonthStart;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2872365fde7de38b994485651904433c)

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the first and the last day for your query:

- **DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(StartDate, -1))** is the first day of month
- **EOMONTH(StartDate)** is the last day of month

```
DECLARE @Date date = '20190901';

SELECT 
    EventTitle AS 'Event Name',
    CompleteAddress AS 'Location',
    UserId AS 'Event Creator'
FROM Event
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date, -1)) AND EOMONTH(@Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your variables to start:

```
  declare @startMonth date = Dateadd(day, -datepart(day, getdate())+1, getdate());
  declare @endMonth date = Dateadd(month, 1, @startMonth);
```

Your `WHERE` clause may look like this:

```
 where (startdate < @startMonth and enddate > @endMonth) -- month completely contained by dates
or startdate < @endMonth and enddate > @endMonth) -- starts in the month and ends after
or startdate < @startmonth and enddate > @startmonth) -- starts before the month and ends in it
or startdate > @startmonth and enddate < @endMonth) -- starts and ends in the month
```

There may be some optimisation that you could do there as well but this explains what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You try use my conditions:

```
WHERE
Month(StartDate) <= Month(getdate()) AND YEAR(StartDate) <= YEAR(getdate()) 
AND (
    (Month(EndDate) >= Month(getdate()) AND YEAR(EndDate) >= YEAR(getdate()) )
    OR EndDate IS NULL
)
```